# how to remove div in a div and rebind it at same position

Tags: jquery

for an li tag i am adding a div with multiple div dynamically like below.

```
 var divStr = "";
 divStr = divStr + "<div id='divTaskDetail"+id+"'>";
 divStr = divStr + "<div id='div1"+id+"'>.......</div>";
 divStr = divStr + "<div id='div2"+id+"'>.......</div>";
 divStr = divStr + "<div id='div3"+id+"'>.....<input class='btnSave' type='button' value='Save'  onclick='javascript:SaveTaskDetails(" + id + ")'/></div>";
 divStr = divStr + "<div id='div4"+id+"'>.......</div>";
 divStr = divStr + "</div>";

 $("#liTask"+id+"").append(divStr);
```

For the "save" button click in "div3" i want to refresh the "div3" region only. ie to rebind the div3 in the same position. 
My code for getting the "div3" is below

```
    function SaveTaskDetails(id)
    {
         var CheckDivObj = $("#liTask"+id+"").children();
         var childNode = CheckDivObj.prevObject[0];
         var childTaskNode = childNode.childNodes[1];
         var childSubTaskNode = childTaskNode.children[3];
         if(childSubTaskNode != null)
         {
             $(""+childSubTaskNode.id+"").detach();
         }
    }
```

I can get the `div3` in `childSubTaskNode` but i want to remove it and rebind in the same position. Is this posible..... 
if so a sample code for detaching and rebinding at same position will be helpfull
Thanks in advance

Comment: Couple of things, firstly instead of `divStr = divStr + 'x';` you can simply use `divStr += 'x';`. Secondly, appending a `div` inside an `li` is not standards compliant. Lastly, having `id` attributes on your appended `div` elements means you will have duplicate id's everywhere, which again is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do an ajax function to get the new div contents and then use the `html` function in jquery to change the html of the div you want to update.

```
$('#div3_save_button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'my_script.php',
        type:'post',
        data:'data=some_data',
        success:function(data){
            // the data variable will contain proper html string for content of div 3, returned from my_script.php
            $('#div3').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This way we do not have to remove and replace div3, just replace the contents of div 3.  See docs for [html here](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a good way to remove an item and place it back in the same spot is to use a placeholder. There may be a better way, but this is what comes to mind.

```
var item = $('#itemToRemove');
var placeHolder = $('<div id="placeholder"></div>');
placeHolder.insertAfter( item );
item.remove();

//Do Stuff here

item.insertBefore( $('#placeholder') );
```